# jquery parent() select <a> in main parent

Tags: jquery

hi i am working on a project i wanna catch of a parent but i could not do it thank you for your advice

this is what is in html part

```
<li> <a class="siralaMain" catid="7" href="#"> <span>Sahil</span> </a>
    <ul style="display: block;">
        <li> <a class="siralaSec active" catid="300" href="#"> </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

`$(this)` references `<a class="siralaSec active" catid="300" href="#">` here

when i made

```
$(this).parent().parent().parent().addClass("active");
```

it addClass to li so it becomes like this

```
<li class="active"> <a class="siralaMain" catid="7" href="#"> <span>Sahil</span> </a>
    <ul style="display: block;">
        <li> <a class="siralaSec active" catid="300" href="#"> </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

but i need to `addClass` to `a` like this

```
<a class="siralaMain active">
```

thanks for any advice

Comment: what if you do .. `$(this).addClass('active');`

Comment: @MohammadAdil -- He needs to add it to the `<a/>` under the parent `<li>`. Not the one he's clicking

Comment: siralaMain is not the parent of this. So no matter what parent selector you try, it will not select it. You have to get to the parent ul and then to it's prev() to select that.

Comment: oops .. I missed that `a` ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(this).closest('.siralaMain').addClass('active');
```

seem like you need to use:

```
 $(this).closest('ul').prev().addClass('active');
```

Comment: I don't think it would work. `closest` works on parent chain and `.siralMain` is not in parent chain.

Answer (score 0):

Ugly `parent` chain is ugly.

```
$(this).parent("li").parent("li").find("a").eq(0).addClass("active");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$(this).closest('li:has(.siralaMain)')
       .find('.siralaMain')
       .addClass('active');
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
$(this).parent().parent().parent().find("a").addClass("active");
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Afgnz/

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 $(this).closest('ul').prev('.siralaMain').addClass('active');
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this -

```
$(this).parents("li:eq(1)").find("a:first").addClass("active");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/4zgM2/1/